# Exclude URLs from a access log sample in JMeter

Tags: apache, logging, jenkins, jmeter, load-testing

I have a Test Plan reading using the Apache access log as an input, through the Access Log Sampler. This test will run on Jenkins.

Although I have a few URLs that I need to exclude, such as favicon.ico requests and some other controllers that are exposed that are not necessary to the context.

Is there any way to exclude these from 1) be actually requested or 2) ignore the calls to these URLs/resources via some pattern matching so they don't appear on the metrics?

I could manipulate the access log before the test and exclude these URLs via bash but I really would like some JMeter feature to allow that.

Comment: I would use shell execute with `sed` to exclude unnecessary strings, all excluded URLs you can define in variables - in this way _Summary report_ or any other will look cleaner (as you won't use overhead logic to filter Jmeter steps) and run time will be much faster.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Dmitry, but since I am using the jmeter-maven-plugin there would be no way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subclass org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.accesslog.SharedTCLogParser to make it exclude the resources you don't want.

Once done, create a jar and add it to jmeter/lib, it will appear as a new parser in the Access Log Sampler. Select it and you're done.

But maybe it's overly complex compared to running a sed before.

You could integrate this sed in JMeter by using [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) to run the sed and do this in a [setup Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) that runs before regular Thread Groups, this would clean up your access log file before it is used by [Access Log Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Access_Log_Sampler).

Comment: Thanks UBIK. I could extend SharedTCPLogParser into another jar and drop it on /lib folder. Thing is, I am running my test using  **jmeter-maven-plugin**, since it builds the project on the fly before running the test, I believe I would need to drop the jar using Maven somehow.